How to correctly implement typing for a generic pinia store in a composable?
Context

VueJs 3.4.19
Typescript 5.3.3
Pinia 2.1.6

In many views of my application, I need to fetch data from an API call. So each view have an onMounted() hook which looks like:
// Users.vue
import { useUserStore } from '@/store/userStore';

const userStore = useUserStore();

onMounted(async() => {
  try {
    await userStore.fetchUsers();
  } catch (err) {
    // my logic to handle errors, 404 etc
  }
});

I want to refactor this part and put all the logic into a Generic composable (don't hesitate to tell me if there is a better way to achieve this)
So I've created a composable called useModelLoader:
// useModelLoader.ts

import {
  StoreDefinition,
  StateTree,
  _GettersTree,
  _ActionsTree
} from "pinia";

export const useModelLoader = <
ID extends string,
S extends StateTree,
G extends _GettersTree<S>,
A extends _ActionsTree,
>(storeDef:  StoreDefinition<ID, S, G, A>, storeModel: keyof S, storeAction: keyof A) => {
  const store = storeDef();

  // TS error here
  // Type 'keyof S' cannot be used to index type 'Store<ID, S, G, A>'.ts(2536)
  const model = store[storeModel];

  // TS error here
  // Type 'keyof A' cannot be used to index type 'Store<ID, S, G, A>'.ts(2536)
  const action = await store[storeAction];
};

So I can use it in my view:
// Users.vue

import { useUserStore } from '@/store/userStore';

const modelLoader = useModelLoader(useUserStore, 'users', 'fetchUsers');

What is working?
In Users.vue:

TS throws an error if the first parameter of useModelLoader is not a StoreDefinition.
TS throw an error if the second parameter of useModelLoader is not a key present in the store state.
TS throw an error if the third parameter of useModelLoader is not an action present in the store actions.
Logging to console store[model] in composable display the correct data.

What is not working

In composable, I've a TS error for model variable:

Type 'keyof S' cannot be used to index type 'Store<ID, S, G, A>'.ts(2536)

In composable, I've a TS error for action variable:

Type 'keyof A' cannot be used to index type 'Store<ID, S, G, A>'.ts(2536)
Question
How can I correctly implement typing for model & action variables? Thanks in advance!

You need to use UnwrapRef<S> and UnwrapRef<A>.
As you can see from the type definition in pinia.d.ts:
export declare type Store<Id extends string = string, S extends StateTree = {}, G = {}, A = {}> = _StoreWithState<Id, S, G, A> & UnwrapRef<S> & _StoreWithGetters<G> & (_ActionsTree extends A ? {} : A) & PiniaCustomProperties<Id, S, G, A> & PiniaCustomStateProperties<S>;

Store<Id, S, G, A> includes UnwrapRef<S>, not S
This is, because the state is made reactive, and any refs (with keys: value), will now be unwrapped, and their keys will be the keys of the .value access instead.
I am not sure why specifically it is also the case for A, but I assume it is a similar reasoning. I couldn't find it in the type definition though.
See your example fixed here: Vue SFC Playground
